# Seeking data for urban and rural areas of United Kingdom?

Tags: data, united-kingdom, postal-code

Is anyone aware of any (commercial) data sets that divide the UK into urban and rural areas based on admin data (e.g. outcode postcodes) and/or physical data (e.g. eastings and northing or lats and longs).

Comment: What Scale? Ordnance Survey Open Data would be a good starting point small scale to large scale http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/opendata-products-grid.html

Comment: I think that this might be better posted to [opendata.se] where you can tag it geospatial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/area-classifications/rural-urban-definition-and-la/rural-urban-definition--england-and-wales-/index.html for the official classification.

Comment: Excellent - thanks! I had to correct the link. Could you please adjust to: http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/area-classifications/rural-urban-definition-and-la/rural-urban-definition--england-and-wales-/index.html

Comment: cut & paste is hard on my phone :-) fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Clicking through on the links from the Rural definition pdf *eventually* gets you to here:
http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/guide-method/geography/products/index.html

Where you can download the 2001 and 2011 definitions at a variety of resolutions...

In response to Mapparz suggestion - I'd be tempted to use the OA level Rural-Urban geography in conjunction with the Open Names database and assign the postcode points with the OA classification:

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-names.html#Specification

Answer (score 0):

Just had to track down the shapefile with this data in.  Took a fair bit looking but eventually got this: http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/oa-ew-bgc-with-rucoa11

RUC classification at output area level (so pretty detailed) in a nice downloadable polygon shapefile.